# Installing ADT 22.0.1 cannot finish

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install ADT 22.0.1 plugin to my Eclipse Indigo. I have downloaded ADT-22.0.1.zip, and started installation. But the "Installing Software" dialog just stopped at 0%. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

After I added the following line to the `hosts` file, the installation went on, and finished soon.

```
74.125.237.1 dl.google.com
```